# How to move body to origin using center of body?

Tags: 3d-design, fusion360

I have a few bodies and I want to move them together so that the center of it is moved to the origin. I don't think the bodies when selected together have the correct center I'd want as I don't think they are all symmetrical. So I would need to move them based on one of the bodies that are symmetrical.

I don't really know how to center the models the way I want with the Move tool. I'm used to Blender where doing this can be done in two mouse clicks. I've tried searching and can't find any way to do this in Fusion 360. The Move tool also doesn't let me use absolute positions, so I can't move a body to a specific position if I want to.

[image: Screenshot of 3D models in Fusion 360]

As can be seen here, I can't get everything to center at the origin, the green line. Near the bottom you can also see the holes aren't lined up and the hole in the middle doesn't line up either, it is too far to the left. I don't know how to line up the center of that model with the center of the other model. I've tried using the "Point to Point" but I can't select the points I would need to do it like the centers of the circles. Even then it still wouldn't be aligned vertically or in the Z-axis.

Comment: This looks more like a software question than a 3D printing question, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No clue about Fusion 360, but if anyone looking for a Blender solution stumbles upon this question, in Layout, Object mode, Object->Origin->Origin to Geometry. Centers object's origin on 'center of mass' of the object.